# Can GMT and UTC be different by a few seconds?

Tags: time

There's a hundred questions asking the difference between GMT and UTC, but they all seem to just say "they're measured differently". My question is, if they're measured differently, one using the sun and the other an atomic clock, can not they differ by a few seconds, and would not this gradually become bigger over time? If not, why not?

Are there any libraries that will return a different date/time for one vs the other?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From a *legal* perspective, there are some historical differences between GMT and UTC.  You can read the Wikipedia articles on [UTC](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coordinated_Universal_Time) and [GMT](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gmt), which explain some of the discrepancies.  But pretty much they are the same thing.  Another Wikipedia article [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Time_zone#Definition) talks about how GMT has been redefined to be the same as UTC.

There is also a good article [here](http://www.diffen.com/difference/GMT_vs_UTC) that explains the difference between them.  In general, from a *computing* perspective, GMT and UTC mean the same thing.  One usually prefers the term UTC in computing because it is unambiguous.

Some people tend to think of GMT as a time zone, while UTC is an overall system of type keeping (as compared to UT1 or TAI).

It's also important to realize that the United Kingdom only observes GMT in the winter months.  In the summer, they observe British Summer Time (BST).  So you can think of `GMT = UTC+00:00` and `BST = UTC+01:00`.

It is interesting to note that many technologies that used to use GMT has been switching to UTC.  For example, look at the display names of time zones on Windows 7 (UTC based) as compared to Windows XP (GMT based).

You will still see GMT on [RFC822](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc0822.txt)/[RFC1123](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc1123.txt) formatted date strings, but even there they have the same meaning as UTC.  (This is just speculation, but [Sir Tim Berners-Lee](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tim_berners_lee) is British, so that might have something to do with why GMT is used in the HTTP spec.)

For all practical matters in modern usage, use UTC. (Unless you are British, then use GMT and wear it proudly!)

Regarding differences between the sun and the atomic clock - that is what [Leap Seconds](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leap_second) are all about.  UT1 will drift, where UTC is adjusted.  But we hardly ever use UT1 in day-to-day computing.  And you would have to have an extremely accurate clock to be affected by leap seconds.  For all practical purposes (with a few very rare exceptions at the OS level), you can safely ignore them.

Comment: I knew UTC factored leap seconds in, but I wasn't sure if GMT did too since the answers I read said it was "based on the sun," but that doesn't appear to be true (anymore). Very informative answer, thank you!

Comment: @Mark: UTC does follow UT1 (within +/- 0.9 seconds) that follows Sun (Earth rotation). See [the 3rd picture](http://www.ucolick.org/~sla/leapsecs/deltat.html).

Answer (score 2):

There's no difference between GMT and UTC. They are exactly the same. They're both measured from the international time standard held in Paris. GMT will continue to exist as a recognised time zone because statutes in the UK and other European countries explicitly refer to it as such.

Comment: So.. "they're measured differently" is a lie? Historically it was true, but UTC essentially replaced GMT and then became a synonym?

Comment: That's the gist of it, although I think GMT ceased to be measured against the sun before UTC came into being.